# Hide <li> tag with a certain <div> tag within it

Tags: jquery

How do I hide the li tag that has a certain div tag within it?

This div tag: **scheduled-new-managed-actionMenu-item** (sorry)

https://jsfiddle.net/x1snfme6/1/

```
<li class="dx-menu-item-wrapper level-2 sub-menu-item">
    One
</li>

<li class="dx-menu-item-wrapper level-2 sub-menu-item">
    Two
</li>

<li class="dx-menu-item-wrapper level-2 sub-menu-item">
  <div class="dx-item dx-menu-item">
    <div class="dx-item-content dx-menu-item-content">
        <div id="scheduled-new-managed-actionMenu-item">
          Three
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: @EvikGhazarian Sorry. I updated it.

Comment: There is not enough detail. You can hide div with $("#scheduled-new-managed-actionMenu-item").hide()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `closest()`

```js
$("#scheduled-new-managed-actionMenu-item").closest("li").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dx-menu-item-wrapper level-2 sub-menu-item">
    One
</li>

<li class="dx-menu-item-wrapper level-2 sub-menu-item">
    Two
</li>

<li class="dx-menu-item-wrapper level-2 sub-menu-item">
  <div class="dx-item dx-menu-item">
    <div class="dx-item-content dx-menu-item-content">
        <div id="scheduled-new-managed-actionMenu-item">
          Three
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

```js
$("li:has(#scheduled-new-managed-actionMenu-item)").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="dx-menu-item-wrapper level-2 sub-menu-item">
    One
  </li>

  <li class="dx-menu-item-wrapper level-2 sub-menu-item">
    Two
  </li>

  <li class="dx-menu-item-wrapper level-2 sub-menu-item">
    <div class="dx-item dx-menu-item">
      <div class="dx-item-content dx-menu-item-content">
        <div id="scheduled-new-managed-actionMenu-item">
          Three
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```